# Where should I put ngClass logic if not in the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a `value -> class` lookup that's used to map values of a property to a given CSS class.

I don't want this logic inline, so at the moment it's in the controller, which keeps the code very simple. However this violates the principle of not having UI logic in controllers. So where else could I put this whilst keeping the code clean?

This is what I currently have:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    var statusClassMap = {
        'PausePending': 'label label-default',
        'Paused': 'label label-primary',
        'ContinuePending': 'label label-info',
        'StartPending': 'label label-info',
        'Running': 'label label-success',
        'StopPending': 'label label-warning',
        'Stopped': 'label label-danger'
    };

    $scope.statusClassMap = statusClassMap;
});
```

View:

```
<td><span data-ng-class="statusClassMap[service.Status]">{{service.Status}}</span></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its perfectly fine in my opinion to have (lengthy and complex)view-related stuff in the controller to keep the view clutter-free.

I would have a model property in the scope that is specifically dedicated for this purpose. This keep everything logically grouped:

```
$scope.myModel = {
    view: {
        // all view-related stuff goes here
    },
    ...
}
```

Use `ng-init` if you still prefer keeping it inside the view:

```
<div ng-init="statusClassMap = {...};">
```

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was commenting right now. This kind of behavioral logic is intended to be used with the `ng-class` directive. The principle the OP is quoting is more related to the standard MVC pattern at server-side, while AngularJS a client-side MVC of sorts.