# Is it common practice to exclude ng-class logic from DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've noticed how cluttered and unreadable the HTML pages get when certain elements on the DOM need various conditional classes with Angular.

Something like this:

```
<div>This is a Message.</div>
```

easily becomes this:

```
<div ng-class="{'red': vm.isRed, 'bold': vm.isBold, 'big': vm.isBig, 'underline': vm.isUnderline}">This is a Message.</div>
```

or something bigger. What I wanted to ask is if there is any common practice to exclude this kind of logic from the HTML?

Something like this perhaps:

```
<div ng-class="objectClass">This is a Message.</div>
```

and having this on the controller:

```
  vm.isRed = true;
  vm.isBold = true;
  vm.isBig = true;
  vm.isUnderline = false;

  vm.objectClass = {
    'red': vm.isRed,
    'bold': vm.isBold,
    'big': vm.isBig,
    'underline': vm.isUnderline,
  };
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jKHNwt1LEOuVOHiG7cov?p=preview

Comment: might be [a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889752/where-should-i-put-ngclass-logic-if-not-in-the-controller).

Answer (score 1):

I typically either use the notation you use in your `objectClass` example or the [array notation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass):

```
<something ng-class="[source]">
```

and

```
$scope.source = ['red', 'bold', 'big'];
```

On the [eBay blog](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/10/01/the-case-against-logic-less-templates/) they defined criteria for good templates:

- not include business logic
- not include a lot of logic
- be easy to read
- be easy to maintain

and while it's easy to avoid the first point, `ng-class` makes it so easy to create logic expressions in templates, that it lures you into the other dangers (that is: just add another expression and at some point you have hard to understand template expressions).

I think the author of the eBay blog hit the nail on the head:

> Although I’m trying to make a case against logic-less templates, that does not mean that I am advocating the other extreme–i.e., a templating language that allows a lot of logic. I find such templating languages, especially those that allow the host programming languages to be used inside the template, to be hard to read, hard to maintain, and simply a bad choice. A JSP template with Java code in it and an Underscore template with JavaScript in it both fall into the category of being a full-of-logic template. JSP and Underscore are not necessarily at fault here; rather, developers often abuse the additional freedom such solutions offer.

So, while I like the freedom `ng-class` gives me, I try to limit myself and push the logic into the controller.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Coming from a rails background, where you can freely organise how your logic interacts with your HTML, having the limitation of working with attributes and directives directly on the HTML elements, just lures you to make these mistakes, which you end up regretting later on, while debugging.